# What does the parameter "source" mean in monaco-editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

There are many methods in monaco-editor that need the parameter "**source**".

For example, the method **trigger** in **IStandaloneCodeEditor**. It's parameters list as belows:

- **source**: *string*

  The source of the call.
- **handlerId**: *string*

  The id of the handler or the id of a contribution.
- **payload**: *any*

  Extra data to be sent to the handler.

I'm confused what does **source** actually mean.

Comment: Truthfully, I'm looking for the same thing, and it's looking more and more like it's an arbitrary field largely used for logging.